# Pyspark substract without selecting column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables

1. Orders - having following columns

   order_id, order_date, order_customer_id, order_status
2. customers - having following columns

   customer_id, customer_fname, customer_lname

I want to write a code using dataframe which is equivalent to following sql query without creating table

```
SELECT customer_fname, customer_lname
FROM  customer
WHERE customer_id NOT IN (SELECT order_customer_id
                          from order)
```

How can i achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From pyspark v2.1.1:**

Using a 'left_anti' join to remove elements that are in the other table:

```
df_result = df_customers.join(df_orders, df_customers.customer_id == df_orders.order_customer_id, 'left_anti')
df_result = df_result.select('customer_fname', 'customer_lname')
```

**Before pyspark v2.1.1:**

Using a 'left_outer' join and removing null values:

```
df_result = df_customers.join(df_orders, df_customers.customer_id == df_orders.order_customer_id, 'left_outer')
df_result = df_result.where('order_id is null')
df_result = df_result.select('customer_fname', 'customer_lname')
```